# Delete en laravel mediante id

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo un método muy simple, que lo unico que hace es cojer de un formulario el id, para borrar la inserción, el tema es que no me funciona:

Vista: Tengo un formulario, en el que seleccionas el id de la vacación y se la paso al método

```
<form action="{{url('vacation/delete')}}" method="POST" role="form"> 
    {{csrf_field()}}

    <legend>Solicitudes Pendientes</legend>
    <select name= "vacation_id" id="inputVacation_id" class = "form-control" required="required">
        @foreach ($vacations as $vacation)
            <option >{{$vacation->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>

    <button type="submit" name="delete" class= "btn btn-primary"><i class="icon-cross2"></i></i></button>
</form>
```

Despues en el controlador:

```
public function delete(Request $request){

    //$vac = Vacation::find($request['vacation_id']);
    //$res=Vacation::where('id',$vac)->delete();
    Vacation::destroy($request['vacation_id']);

    return redirect()->back();
}

public function delSolicitudes()
{
    $vacations =  \DB::table('vacations')
        ->select('workers.name','vacations.id' ,'vacations.type','vacations.date_from','vacations.date_to','vacations.observations','vacations.aceptado')
        ->join('workers','workers.id','=','vacations.worker_id')
        ->where(['vacations.aceptado' => '0'])
        ->get();

    return view('vacation.deletevac', ['vacations' => $vacations]);              
}
```

Ya veis que simplemente tengo la consulta para obtener los datos, que realmente no me hace falta ninguno mas que el id, pero cuando le doy a borrar no borra nada, no da error, pero no hace nada tampoco,

Pregunta 2: Comentar que he intentado usar el mismo formulario, que utilizo para hacer update con el delete, y no me ha funcionado, seria posible hacer update y delete en el mismo form? considerando que hay que falsear los métodos?

Saludos y gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buenas creo que el error es que en el ***< option >*** no le pasas ningun value

```
<legend>Solicitudes Pendientes</legend>
   <select name= "vacation_id" id="inputVacation_id" class = "form-control" required="required">
       @foreach ($vacations as $vacation)
          <option name= "vacation" value="{{$vacation->id}}">{{$vacation->name}}</option>
       @endforeach
    </select>
```

Respondiendo a tu segunda pregunta, si se puede hacer, usando dos botones, uno modificar y otro borrar. En el controlador usas una condición si pulsas botón modificar acción update si pulsas botón borrar acción delete.

Yo no lo haría así, lo haría como nos recomienda Laravel con dos ruta, y dos funciones. Queda mas limpio y simple a futuro.

Comment: Lo intente pero como el boton lo tengo dentro de una tabla en el propio foreach dentro del formulario, me coje por defecto update siempre y llama a update, respecto al option, la id la recibo correctamente en el controlador, haciendo un dd($vacation) (por ejemplo) veo que recibe el id, pero a la hora de hacer el delete no lo hace, ni con delete ni destroy, me parece un poco absurdo para el planteamiento de api que he hecho meter dos vistas una para borrar y otra actualizar, pero bueno es como lo tengo, probare lo del option, gracias :)

Comment: Me funciono!!! muchas gracias Unai, menuda tonteria..

Answer (score 1):

cuando estas pasando o recogiendo valores desde una vista para manipularlos en el controlador, deberías tener lo siguiente:

```
<form action="{{url('vacation/delete')}}" method="POST" role="form"> 
    {{csrf_field()}}

    <legend>Solicitudes Pendientes</legend>
    <select name= "vacation_value" id="inputVacation_id" class = "form-control" required="required">
        @foreach ($vacations as $vacation)
            <option value="{{ $vacation->id }}">
                {{$vacation->name}}
            </option>
        @endforeach
    </select>

    <button type="submit" name="delete" class= "btn btn-primary"><i class="icon-cross2"></i></i></button>
</form>
```

Del modo anterior, cuando pasas los datos el valor del id es dinámico y existente, pues esta siendo generado por cada consulta y como puedes notar también el value es el valor que me va a ayudar a trabajar en el controlador.

Ya en el controlador puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
$tabla = Tabla::find($id);
$tabla->delete();
```

Lo anterior a manera de ejemplo, checa el nombre que le coloque al select y el nombre es el mismo en el método get en el controlador

Comment: Interesante aportacion buscar por el id de la tabla, muchas gracias Alfredo lo probare